# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException coming

Tags: java

```
public float getAccountBalance()    {       //log.debug("in getAccountBalance");
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(smsServiceUrl);
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));
    method.setParameter("Username", username);
    method.setParameter("PIN", PIN);
    method.setParameter("AvailableCredit", "");
    String result = new String();
    try {
        result = doHttpServiceRequest(method);
    //  log.debug("result is: " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    //  log.warn(e.toString());
    }

    String[] retArray = result.split(" ");
    return Float.valueOf(retArray[1]);

}
```

Here i am getting ArrayIndexOutBoundException. can any one tell me how to rectify that exception?

Comment: Please format your code more readably when asking a question, and tell us the value of `result`. Presumably it doesn't contain a space.

Comment: Use return Float.valueOf(retArray[0]);

Comment: I would assume that `result` may not contain any spaces, meaning that split will create an array of size 1 (index 0).

Comment: Have you tried printing the content of the result variable ?

Comment: No. i just want to retrive the data present in the String array. & that will return that value to the calling env.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] retArray = result.split(" ");
return Float.valueOf(retArray[1]);
```

will assume that there is at least two elements in the retArray - this may not be the case.
Test with `retArray.length`

Comment: By doing this getting Exception like
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-1&Report"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at SMSServiceJava.CSoftHttpClientSMSService.getAccountMessageLimit(CSoftHttpClientSMSService.java:56)
 at SMSServiceJava.CSoftHttpClientSMSService.main(CSoftHttpClientSMSService.java:223)

Comment: well read the error - is `1&Report` an Integer - NO !  Programming is not like mind reading.  You have to be very precise is what you want your program to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting the exception here:

```
String[] retArray = result.split(" ");
return Float.valueOf(retArray[1]);
```

If you split according to `" "`, sometimes there might be no second element. You need to check that:

```
String[] retArray = result.split(" ");
if(retArray.length >= 2) {
   return Float.valueOf(retArray[1]);
}
```

Note that I write the condition only to demonstrate the issue. You might want to reconsider your logic.
Also recall that arrays in Java are *zero-based*, when you return `retArray[1]`, you're actually returning the second element in the array.

Comment: By doing this i am getting NumberFormatException.

Comment: @Deepu That's something else. Make sure `result` contains `float` values.

Comment: Yes it result contains float values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check first, if array have any data or not

```
if(retArray.length>0)
{
  // do your thing
}
else
{
   // no element found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check String result, either it will be empty or it will have data which doesn't have space delimiter also check the length of the retArray before access retArray[1] (by retArray[1] actually you are trying to access 2 element in the array.)